# Weird json request via curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, curl

I'm sending json request via curl to my local web server

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d {"name":"Stanford University", "subdomain":"stanford"} http://localhost:3000/rest/v1/groups.json
```

But in my rails app in params i'm getting

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"Stanford University", "subdomain"=>"stanford", "group"=>{"name"=>"Stanford University", "subdomain"=>"stanford"}}
```

Where did that hash group came from, and how do i controll it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`. You likely have `wrap_parameters` enabled for JSON requests.

You can disable this option in the above file with

```
wrap_parameters false
```

**Recommended Reading:** http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to send it into Json Format

Try Following

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"name\":\"Stanford University\", \"subdomain\":\"stanford\"}"
```

OR

```
hash = {"name":"Stanford University", "subdomain":"stanford"}
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "#{hash.to_json}" http://localhost:3000/rest/v1/groups.json
```